# how to resolve failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount3554908678/Dockerfile:

Tags: java, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to build a docker image on windows 10 using visual code

Dockerfile:

```
FROM openjdk
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN javac dockerSample.java
CMD ["java","dockerSample"]
```

Docker file path `C:\Users\User\Desktop\New folder 1\Dockerfile`

After running this command, I'm getting the following error:

> C:\Users\User>docker build -t javaapp1 . [+] Building 0.0s (0/0)
> docker:default 2023/07/15 22:22:19 http2: server: error reading
> preface from client //./pipe/docker_engine: file has already been
> close[+] Building 4.0s (2/2) FINISHED
> docker:default  => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
> 1.4s  => => transferring dockerfile: 2B                                                                                 0.0s  => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  1.9s  => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s ERROR: failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount3554908678/Dockerfile: no such file
> or directory

Comment: You need to run the command from the folder with the Dockerfile. Use `cd` to change directories.

Answer (score 4):

Ah, got it!

You ran the following command:
`C:\Users\User>docker build -t javaapp1`
from `C:\Users\User` directory, which don't contain your `Dockerfile`.
To get it working, first change the directory to one that contains your `Dockerfile`, which is `C:\Users\User\Desktop\New folder 1` and then run docker build command

Hope it helped! ✌️

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command from the directory where the dockerfile is located.

In this case assuming your docerkfile is sample.Dockerfile.

```
docker build -t javaapp1 - < sample.Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 0):

I had given **incorrect docker file name** i.e. **"Dockerfile"** and I had named the file **"DockerFile"**. So the build was failing.